# QGIS v3.10.6 and MacOS 11 (Big Sur): Compatible or not?

Tags: qgis, macos, compatibility

I have not found any conclusive answer from Web searches, including QGIS Web site, whether QGIS v3.10.6 is compatible with the current MacOS 11 (Big Sur) on an Intel-based Macbook Pro (2019).

Any help from readers here?

Comment: What question does the [official download-site](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#mac) leave open when stating "Mac Installer Packages for macOS High Sierra (10.13) and newer."

Comment: The open-ended nature of the statement at the download site is that it could have been written before the release of macOS 11. There are a number of other programs that do not yet work with macOS 11. So, before I make the major decision to upgrade to that macOS, I wanted to verify from someone with experience that QGIS works with macOS 11.